# How to pass data from an angular service to an external JS lib?

Tags: javascript, angular

In the angular project I have a service that makes call into server to get login in and get back a bearer TOKEN that will be used to call to web services.

In fact, I'm using external JavaScript lib (piwik.js), I made some change on the lib (adding new methods the make calls to some api on order servers using that TOKEN).

What I did not figure out here, is how to pass that TOKEN from the angular service to this external JS lib?

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if that js library gives a mechanism to provide data to it, it doesn't matter whether you provide it from service of component. please figure out how that js library expects the data.